# How to fetch all the values present in the array related to the key in json

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got synonyms  for some words , 
how can i get all the synonyms present in the array for the entered value .

For example if the user enters

**rain** in the text field , i need to fetch the **water , rainfall and showers**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwEPY/18/

```
var json = [
    {
        "rain": [
            "water",
            "rainfall",
            "showers"
        ]
    },
    {
        "happy": [
            "blessed",
            "delighted"
        ]
    }
]

$(document).on('click', '#btn ', function(event) {
    var text = $.trim($("#txt").val());
});
```

Could you please let me know how to fetch items .

Answer (score 2):

First of, I think that your `json` structure could be better, but for this structure you can do something as below:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn ', function(event) {
    var text = $.trim($("#txt").val());
    for(var i = 0; i< json.length; i++){
       for(var key in json[i]){
           if(key == text){
               alert(json[i][key]);
           }
       }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rwEPY/21/)**

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vijayP/rwEPY/20/

You can use `$.each` to loop through `object` and `array`

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn ', function(event) {
    var text = $.trim($("#txt").val());

    $.each(json,function(i,obj){

        $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
          if(key == text)
          {
              alert(value);
          }
        });

    });
});
```